# When set on a div in another css file it doesn't work, when set as body, it works

Tags: php, html, css

```
<script>
    var obj = {{ data|raw }}
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)));  
</script>
```

This is the body of my html file. The problem is that when I make a new css file - **metadata.css** just for this html file and it contains this:

```
body {
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    width: 770px;
}
```

everything works. But I don't need this new file. So I tried to change my html to this:

```
<div class="metadata">
    <script>
        var obj = {{ data|raw }}
        document.body.innerHTML = "";
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)));  
    </script> 
</div>
```

and add the style for the div in the css file where is all my css and it became this:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

table,th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 17px;
}

th {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

td {
   padding: 3px 5px; 
}

a.pagination {
    margin: 9px;
}

span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.find_page {
    margin: 20px;
}

form input {
    width: 50px;
}

.metadata {
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    width: 770px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

but the problem is that in this way, it doesn't work - I think that the div is not styled at all. Can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Does the resulting div have it's class set to metadata?

Comment: When I see the code from the browser? Yes, it has it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your javascript is not targeting the container it's in.

```
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)));
```

is going to target the body of the document since it's using `document.body`, and not care about where the code is defined (and therefore the class of the container is entirely discarded...actually erased by the `innerHTML = ""` statement.  What you'd be looking for is `document.write` which will output in the place of definition (and with no clearing statement).

```
 document.write(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)));
```

This in general should be replaced by explicitly tageted selection and unobtrusive JavaScript when you start to do anything more than one-off code.

Comment: Just one more thing - how to set it to write from the top left corner, bacause it starts a bit down and in right

Comment: You can use CSS to handle that.  If the content is in the div and the div is positioned where you want then the padding and text-alignment should work as you'd expect on that content.